# Wanted to know about ZPL to image conversion

Tags: base64, zpl

I have a requirement in my project where in I need to convert the ZPL code to image  format. We are not suppose to use Labelary as it is a lisenced product and my clients will not give permission.
Can you please help with an approach?

Comment: Adding a reference:

Answer (score 0):

Use the [official docs](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) for getting started. With these informations you can start writing a parser which then can convert the ZPL label to an image. But be aware, that this can be a very timeconsuming task!
Since you don't have have specified your favourite programming language, I can't give you any further advice.